# Que outros termos existem tipo "terno", para outros números?

Tags: vocabulário

Temos os números ordinais, `primeiro`, `segundo`, etc., para representar 1, 2, etc.

Temos termos como `bi`, `tri`, `tetra`, `penta` para representar 2, 3, 4, 5... como se chamam esses termos?

Temos também o termo `terno` para representar 3. Quais são os termos, nessa linha, para representar 2, 4, 5, 6, etc e quais os nomes dessas representações? quaterno, quinterno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 1: Ás;
- 2: Duque;
- 3: Terno;
- 4: Quadra;
- 5: Quina;
- 6: Sena;
- 7: Bisca/Manilha.

Acho que não há mais numerais nesta série.

Habitualmente só são usados em Portugal quando se joga às cartas, para chamar as cartas pelo nome conforme o seu valor.

Como os jogos mais comuns são a sueca, o burro, e a bisca, nos quais é usado um baralho de 40 cartas, não costuma haver cartas numéricas com valores maiores que o sete. Então, é muito raro ser levantado o problema de chamar essas cartas pelo nome. Diz-se simplesmente "o oito", "o dez", juntando o determinante ao numeral mais comum para as denominar.

Comment: @bad_coder Se nos basearmos no jogo Guritipau, a continuação da tua lista, depois do "sena", [seria](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guritipau): *Setóna; Oitóna; Novóna*. Talvez você ache que valha a pena mencionar na resposta.

Comment: bad_coder, a outra resposta fez-me reparar que só respondes à segunda das duas perguntas feitas. Não queres tentar incluir uma resposta à primeira? («como se chamam esses termos?»)

Answer (score 1):

Os termos bi, tri, tetra, penta, etc são chamados de prefixos matemáticos.

Comment: Juliano, respondes à primeira pergunta posta («como se chamam esses termos?») mas não à segunda («"terno" para representar 3. Quais são os termos, nessa linha, para representar 2, 4, 5, 6, etc e quais os nomes dessas representações?»). A tua resposta ficava mais sólida se respondesses também à outra metade das duas perguntas que foram postas na *Question*.

Comment: Outra dica é incluir links que suportem ou complementem a tua resposta. Nesse caso, por exemplo essa lista da Wikipedia viria a calhar: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_prefixos_matem%C3%A1ticos

Answer (score 0):

Numerais distributivos ou coletivo

1 quina de maçãs = 5 maçãs
1 terno de ovos =  3 ovos
1 quaterno de pães = 4 pães
1 sena de números =  o sonho de todo mundo na loteria, 6 números

singular
par ou bieno (não confundir com biênio)
terno ou trinca
quaterno ou quadra
quina
sena
septena
octena
NOVENA = ja sabem pq significa novena não?
Dezena
duzia / dozena
trezena
vintena
centena

do Latim

singuli
bini
terni
quaterni
quini
seni
septeni
octeni
noveni
deni
undeni
duodeni
tredeni
vinteni
centeni